# Pass value from child directive isolated scope to parent directive isolated scope and trigger watch of parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**The current situation:**

I have two directives:

A modal dialog from [GitHub](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngModal) with for completeness [the code of the modal](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngModal/blob/master/dist/ng-modal.js) plus an example in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/aDuJIku/2).

A custom directive, branch finder, with the following directive code.

```
angular.module('sfNgBranchFinder', ['sfNgFieldWrapper', 'sfNgLabelsService'])
.directive('sfNgBranchFinder', function (sfNgLabelsService, sfNgBranchService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        required: '^modal-dialog',
        scope: {
            show: '=',
            submitted: '@',
            branchFinderTitle: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //Check the getLabel function in the branchfinder and 
            scope.getLabel = function (key) {
                return sfNgLabelsService.getLabel(key);
            }
                scope.getErrorLabel = function (key) {
                var errorLabelKey = scope.errorLabelKey;
                if (!errorLabelKey) {
                    errorLabelKey = 'EM_' + scope.labelKey;
                }
                return sfNgLabelsService.getLabel(errorLabelKey + "_" + key);
            }
            scope.searchBranch = function (branchFinderForm) {
                alert("searching!");
            }

            return scope.hideModal = function () {
                scope.modalShown = false;
                return scope.show = false;
            }
        },
        templateUrl: '/SFF/Content/UILib/3.0.0/directives/templates/sf-ng-    branchfinder.tpl.html'
    };
});
```

In my html this looks like:

```
<modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='500px' class="sf-dialog">
    <div sf-ng-branch-finder branch-finder-title="Find your branch" show='modalShown' ></div>
</modal-dialog>
```

The custom directive has a template, nothing special in it, some basic html and that all works fine. I have only one problem.

**The problem**

An additional cancel button (so besides the X at the top right corner) doesn't trigger the show='modalShown' of the parent.

So basically, my cancel button triggers the scope.hideModal function in the directive correctly and adjusts the scope.show as well, but the adjusted value doesn't get passed to the show of the parent or at least doesn't trigger the watch in the modal dialog logic:

```
      scope.$watch('show', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal && !oldVal) {
          document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
        } else {
          document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.overflow = "";
        }
        if ((!newVal && oldVal) && (scope.onClose != null)) {
          return scope.onClose();
        }
      });
```

**The question**

How can I make the above situation work?

What is needed to pass a value from a child directive with an isolated scope, to its parent directive that also has an isolated scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atsh20ax/) reproduces your problem.

**The problem**

The `modalDialog` directive creates its own scope, so the 2 `modalShown` variables in your HTML are not the same variable. They are indenpendent and that's why changing the inner one doesn't change the outer one.

**The solution**

To make them the same variable, make them the property of a common object.

```
<modal-dialog show='modal.shown' width='500px' class="sf-dialog">
    <div sf-ng-branch-finder branch-finder-title="Find your branch" show='modal.shown' ></div>
</modal-dialog>
```

And in your controller you should have `$scope.modal = {shown: true}`

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atsh20ax/1/) where it works. This is the recommended way of using `$scope` in Angular. You should have a dot in your variable names in the view.

**Even better**

To help you use this technique, the Angular team added a new feature in Angular 1.2 named the 'Controller As' syntax, where instead of manipulating the scope in the  controller, the controller manipulates its own objet that is published in the scope.

```
<div ng-controller="ModalController as modal">
    <modal-dialog show='modal.shown' width='500px' class="sf-dialog">
        <div sf-ng-branch-finder branch-finder-title="Find your branch" show='modal.shown' ></div>
    </modal-dialog>
```

And in the controller:

```
.controller('ModalController', function () {
    this.shown = true;
});
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atsh20ax/2/). 'Controller As' is the way to go to simplify scope management.

Comment: THanks! Will try this. I've only recently started using angularjs and still need to get formal training in it but I'm already trying to learn alot by myself. Because of this I'm not yet experienced in the usage of scope and how to use it efficiently.

Comment: In the meantime I've implemented your suggestions and it works. I'm busy trying to understand the details of it all so I can do it myself better next time. Thanks for the help!